# Bulk apply store categories to a range of products

Tags: category

I am new to Magento and I deleted all the store categories the previous store owner had put in and I created all new store categories that I preferred.  I didn't realise this would make all my products invisible until I assigned them categories!

Is there a way I can apply selected store categories to a range of products?

Say for example I have a range of products:

Holden Commodore potato peeler red
Holden Commodore potato peeler blue
Holden Commodore potato peeler orange

And I wanted to put all of them in parent category Holden, sub-category peeler.  Is there a way I can select all my Holden Commodore potato peelers and add them to these categories?

I was hoping to avoid having to add them to categories one by one as we have over 7000 items in our Magento store...

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When editing a category there is a tab that allows adding products in bulk.

Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Select Category to edit

Select the "Category Products" tab (should be far right tab)

Set the first dropdown in grid to "Any" (this dropdown filters based on if product is in category or not).

Type "Holden Commodore potato peeler" in to the "Name" filter (just below "Name" label in top column).

Click "Search" button (far right top of grid next to "Reset Filter")

You should now see the products that match the filters options

Check the checkbox on far left of grid (this checkbox controls if you want to add/remove the product).

After you have checked all products you want added, then click the "Save Category" button in top right of the edit page.

Depending on your system, you may need to run indexes and flush cache before the products will actually display in the category.

Comment: You are an absolute legend.  This is EXACTLY the info I needed!  You've just saved me dozens of hours of work.  Thank you so much for that!

Comment: This has saved my life. Thankyou.

Comment: Is there a way to filter products by attribute for example in order to bulk add them to a category? Thanks.